# How to search keywords split by comma in django in AdminModel?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to make custom search that accept the separated keywords by ',' like this example
[image]

and I want get results that seperated in two columns [name, status], status has two value result "exist" or "not exist", how to make it using django and python

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
class UnsplitableUnicode(unicode):
    "An object that behaves like a unicode string but cannot be split()"
    def split(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return [self]

class MultiWordSearchChangeList(ChangeList):
    "Changelist that allows searches to contain spaces"
    def get_query_set(self, request):
        self.query = UnsplitableUnicode(self.query)
        return super(MultiWordSearchChangeList, self).get_query_set(request)


class TbldomainsPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','status',)
    #raw_id_fields = ('name',)
    search_fields = ['name', ]
    def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
        return MultiWordSearchChangeList
```

*I wrote this python code in models.py for search word without splitting by comma*

Answer (score 0):

It's stated very clearly in Django documentation that search_fileds is split by spaces.
So, following this example, it’s currently not possible to search for all records in which first_name is exactly 'john winston' (containing a space).

You can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results).

Maybe you have to modify source code of Django to customize your search forms.